# Link changing URL but not the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, ant-design-pro

I am using Ant design breadcrumbs. I am trying to change the page using link and pushing the URL, I can see the URL change but the page in not changing.

I tried using Link, then creating a function for onClick but everything just change the URL.

```
Route: 
<Route exact path="/assistant/:wId/skill/xyz/:sid" component={ xyz } />

Tried process 1: 

<Breadcrumb separator=">">
 <Breadcrumb.Item 
     onClick={this.redirectToParam2}>   
     {param2}
 </Breadcrumb.Item>
</Breadcrumb>

redirectToParam2 = () => {            
     this.props.history.push(`/assistant/${wId}/skill/xyz/${sId}`);
 }

Tried process 2:

<Breadcrumb separator=">">
   <Breadcrumb.Item>    
     <Link to= {`/assistant/${wId}/skill/xyz/${sId}`}>
     {param2}
     </Link>
  </Breadcrumb.Item>
</Breadcrumb>
```

Even I tried without the Breadcrumbs component but it's still not changing the page.

I want the page to change as soon as the URL changes.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is Link imported from 'react-router-dom'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";



 <Breadcrumb separator=">">
   <Breadcrumb.Item>    
     <Link to= {`/assistant/${wId}/skill/xyz/${sId}`}>
     {param2}
     </Link>
  </Breadcrumb.Item>
</Breadcrumb>
```

Comment: This is what I did written as second above but it didn't worked. @Dixit Savaliya

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into, is that with changing the parameters used as props for the *xyz* component, the component is not replaced but gets new properties. Since nothing changes, i'm assuming you have state that gets filled either in the *constructor* or *ComponentWillMount*/*ComponentDidMount*.

React class components have a lifecycle function for this: componentDidUpdate.

> **componentDidUpdate()** is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.
>
> Use this as an opportunity to operate on the DOM when the component has been updated. This is also a good place to do network requests as long as you compare the current props to previous props (e.g. a network request may not be necessary if the props have not changed).

*Quote from react docs, See: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate*

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if ((this.props.params.match.sid !== prevProps.params.match.sid) || 
      (this.props.params.match.wid !== prevProps.params.match.wid)) {
    this.populateState(this.props.params.match); //fill your state
  }
}
```